# Sharepoint 2013 Assertion Failed

Tags: firefox, sharepoint, properties, assertion

When I try to open Properties section of a list in Sharepoint 2013, if I'm using Firefox, I get this MessageBox:

"Assertion Failed: Couldn't find hard bounding box. Did someone override the 'overflow' property on the document body?

Break into debugger?"

If I answer "No", it works perfectly. But I don't know why I have this error and I want to fix it. If I use IExplorer, it doesn't give any exception.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please follow this link. i hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814640/assertion-failed-break-into-debugger