# Assertion Failed: Break into debugger

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I am facing this assertion error in every list which is included a column type of managed metadata.

Even if I create a new custom list and add one metadata type column, this error is popping up when I click on quick edit.

Can anyone give a clue where I can start to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

This issue occurred because the debugging mode was enabled in the SharePoint web.config file for that web application.

I disabled the debug mode and reset the IIS AND the error is gone. :)